# Separating copy/move assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, assignment-operator

I've read here: [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics), under secondary title: **Special member functions**, the reasons why we should unify both copy assignment operator & move assignment operator into a single move\copy assignment operator,

but what if we wish to forbid copying or moving? should in this case I indicate "deleted" on the forbidden constructor and implement the other? (i.e. separating between the two).

If so, what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Just separate them, like the first two code block in that section

Comment: are you referring to `copy-and-swap` idiom for the assignment operators?

Comment: vu1p3nox, 
Yes I am.

Comment: Well, what operations do you want your class to support? It is up to you.

Comment: Also, the "unification" shown has trade-offs. Personally I don't think it is such a good idea.

Comment: I want to forbid copying, but allow moving. To my understanding, the move/copy assignment operators both uses the copy constructor which is forbidden in my case, or if I'm wrong, how should I implement a move assignment operator which doesn't use the copy constructor?

Comment: you create the normal move assignment operator: `X& X::operator=(X&&);`

Comment: Thanks!

juanchopanza, what are the trade-offs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a class that is movable but not copyable, you should implement the move constructor and mark the copy constructor as deleted.

The copy-and-swap pattern still works (more of a move-and-swap, really).  Since the parameter can only be move constructed, only move assignment will be available.

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass(MyClass&& other) {
        // Do your move here
    }
    MyClass(const MyClass& other) = delete;

    MyClass& operator=(MyClass other) {
        // You can still use copy-and-swap (move-and-swap, really)
        // Since MyClass is non-copyable, only move assignment will be available
    }
};
```

Or you could just create a move assignment operator (`MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& other)`) instead.  The default copy assignment operator will be implicitly deleted if you declare a move constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Understood completely.